# bash : cat commands output only if it success

Tags: bash, shell, cat, overwrite, out

I'm trying to redirect a command's output in a file only if the command has been successful because I don't want it to erase its content when it fails.
(`command` is reading the file as input)

I'm currently using

```
cat <<< $( <command> ) > file;
```

Which erases the file if it fails.

It's possible to do what I want by storing the output in a temp file like that:

```
<command> > temp_file && cat temp_file > file
```

But it looks kinda messy to me, I want avoid manually creating temp files *(I know* `<<<` *redirection is creating a temp file)*

I finally came up with this trick

```
cat <<< $( <command> || cat file) > file;
```

Which will not change the contents of the file... but which is even more messy I guess.

Comment: is `command` by any chance also reading from `file`? does `command` generate any output when it fails and if so is said output sent to stdout, stderr or both?

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes `command` reading from `file`, the output when it fails is sent to stderr which leave the stdout blank and cat blanks the file

Comment: Just write to a temporary file (on the same file system), and rename that file atomically if the command succeeds. `command > temp_file && mv temp_file file`. It's not messy: it's *explicit* and safe. (Cleaning up the temp file if the command fails can be a little messier, but `trap` can help with that.)

Comment: @chepner yes I think I'll use that reluctantly, but if there is a way to conditionnaly change the output redirection it could be great.
I'll search about `trap`. Thanks

Comment: Output redirection is just syntax for replacing the file descriptor a new process sees. It doesn't provide any kind of in-shell buffer that can be discarded if the process ends up failing. I'm not aware of any shell provides that kind of implicit buffering.

Comment: If you're primarily concerned with it being ugly, have you considered writing your own one-liner shell function that automates the process so you can simply run `safelysave file command --flags` or similar?

Comment: @thatotherguy it's possible yeah, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps capture the output into a variable, and echo the variable into the file if the exit status is zero:

```sh
output=$(command) && echo "$output" > file
```

Testing

```sh
$ out=$(bash -c 'echo good output') && echo "$out" > file
$ cat file
good output

$ out=$(bash -c 'echo bad output; exit 1') && echo "$out" > file
$ cat file
good output
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works well, I will stand for it. I had tried this but I had forgotten the double quotes so I was losing the `\n`

Answer (score -1):

Remember, the **>** operator replaces the existing contents of the file with the output of the command. If you want to save the output of multiple commands to a single file, you’d use the **>>** operator instead. This will append the output to the end of the file.

For example, the following command will append output information to the file you specify:

```
ls -l >> /path/to/file
```

So, for log the command output only if it success, you can try something like this:

```
until command
do
  command >> /path/to/file
done
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; it would leave (possibly partial) output from the command whether or not it succeeds at the *end* of the original file rather than replacing the original file with the full output of a successful command.

Comment: I need the `>` operator because i want the old content replaced by the new (if the command does not fail), but thanks for the answer

Comment: @Lommoez i just edited my answer, hope I was helpful.

Comment: This still doesn't address the possibility of partial output from a failed command accumulating in the old file, nor does it address removing the old content when the command *does* succeed.